# I've seen a transaction with 24 ancestors in the mempool, Is there a sensible use of this?

Tags: mempool

I've seen a transaction with 24 ancestors in thee mempool, Is there a sensible use of this? Or is a kind of spam or something else?

It got mined on block 613101

```
$ getmempoolentry 132c52367b5e8c6abe87eee8bc60032c58f3d1296b8ca216373d924d94013d45
```

```
{
  "fees": {
    "base": 0.00000202,
    "modified": 0.00000202,
    "ancestor": 0.00019743,
    "descendant": 0.00000202
  },
  "size": 202,
  "fee": 0.00000202,
  "modifiedfee": 0.00000202,
  "time": 1579178958,
  "height": 613089,
  "descendantcount": 1,
  "descendantsize": 202,
  "descendantfees": 202,
>  "ancestorcount": 24,
  "ancestorsize": 4848,
  "ancestorfees": 19743,
  "wtxid": "34799217c58ef6da2417db2cc7ddf0715f9d0ab86926b3fd99e23e1ce92968c4",
  "depends": [
    "676a48b91e030f2d757b9ae877d452b0d88a3304d19f0960d988d69fc9c180f2"
  ],
  "spentby": [
  ],
  "bip125-replaceable": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the ancestor transactions this looks like someone is writing chunks of data to the chain.

The couple of transactions I looked at all have an `OP_RETURN` output and then send to `bc1qraz56wyj28km560u2pyyml9dr3uaxv9sts67ct`, chaining them together.

Looking at the `OP_RETURN` data, this could also be some kind of timestamping or another sort of anchoring as the data doesn't look random:

```
000c486100023...
000c487000029...
000c48740002e...
000c487500024...
000c48780002f...
000c487b0002a...
000c487e0002a...
000c48810002c...
```

It's hard to say. Maybe someone else has more insight into this.